# WhatsApp call/LINE call over phone speaker and Spotify music over Bluetooth speaker at the same time

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, bluetooth, spotify, line, loudspeaker

I connected my Samsung Galaxy S7 edge to my car's Bluetooth and started to call my friend using *the phone's loudspeaker* on WhatsApp or LINE app. However, I also want to listen to music on the Spotify app, but through my *Bluetooth speaker* on my car.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [Youcanic - 5 Ways To Play Music From Phone To Car Radio](https://www.youcanic.com/article/play-music-phone-car), you can use 
[Mono Bluetooth router app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.codococo.monomono) or other similar ones.

Let us know about the sound quality.